# How to add Space between Currency Symbol and Price?

Tags: price, currency

Before you put your answer I want to declare few things here we are using another currency name is Rupee (PKR) not US dollar so what i need to do to put space like this `Rs. 23`, i tried from admin panel to put `&nbsp` like this thing ahead symbol manually but from this way `&nbsp` is also showing on customer order emails and PDF order invoices which makes all things ugly. So there is another way to put space between this currency (Rs. ) ?? please help me to do this, so far i tried all possible ways which are described on internet but not getting success.. Please help me to fix it, it important to put space between this currency and price figures.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You have to add empty space after Currency Symbol (System > Manage Currency > Symbols). For example: `PKR` 
[image]

Comment: Okay, but why currency and price figures is showing up and down in shopping cart but showing fine in product pages.. please see the snapshot. http://i63.tinypic.com/2yv2ft1.png

Comment: That should be related to your css. Check if the wrapper div width is too small to fit it.